# Gridview1.beginedit(true) selects cell instead of editing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Framework: .net 4.0 WinForms
Control: DataGridView

I am trying to make a specific cell of datagridview editable based on some conditon, below is my code

`DataGridView1.ClearSelection();
 DataGridViewCell cell = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
 DataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
 DataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);`

DataGridView1.BeginEdit(true) is supposed to edit a cell, but it is not editing a cell.

Please help me out how can i set the cell to edit mode ?

Note: I am trying this code in cell enter event

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set `DataGridView1`'s property [EditMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to [EditProgrammatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridvieweditmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The default is [EditOnKeystrokeOrF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridvieweditmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Try this code in [CellClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event hadler